How do I deserialise a class property of type Object in VB Net with System.Json
In VB .Net, I use System.Json to (de)serialise a class called Model. This class has a list of changes, where a change has three properties: PropertyName, OrignalValue and NewValue.
The PropertyName contains the name of the changed property of the Model class e.g., the Demand. The value properties are filled with instances of other classes; e.g. Location, Demand, etc.
Public Class Demand
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property Description As String
End Class

Public Class Change
   Public Property PropertyName As String
   Public Property OriginalValue As Object
   Public Property NewValue As Object
End Class

Public Class Model
   Public Property Changes As New List(Of Change)
End Class

During serialisation of the class Model, all seems to go well when looking at the JSON file. During deserialisation, the PropertName value is deserialised directly too but the value properties are still some sort of JSON string value that need to be deserialised a second time?
As a solution, I find online the recommendation to create a JsonConverter. However, when implemented, I get a 'depricated' error for the line:
Public Overrides Function Read(ByRef reader As Utf8JsonReader, typeToConvert As Type, options As JsonSerializerOptions) As Object

In this post, I read that Json conversion is not supported (anymore?) in VB .Net: GitHub link
Any thoughts or solutions on how to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Update: not sure why I didn't came across this web page earlier, but here is the reason for not being able to override the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/visual-basic-support

If it works in C#, you could write just that part of the program in C#.
